# I want to copy a whole text file line into a vector of strings, but the content is not fully copied

Tags: c++, string, file

I'm trying to copy a file row into a vector of strings, but I don't get the result I'm hoping for. Here's the code:

```
AmtCatania bus;
ifstream aprifile;
string buffer;
string partenza;
string destinazione;
string data;
string ora_partenza;
string ora_arrivo;
string ritardo;
string tratta;
vector <string> corsa;
aprifile.open("corse.txt");
if(!aprifile.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Registro non aperto!" << endl;
    return -1;
}

while(getline(aprifile, buffer , '\n'))
{

    corsa.push_back(buffer);
    aprifile >> partenza >> destinazione >> data >> ora_partenza >> ora_arrivo >> ritardo;
    bus.addTratta(tratta);
    bus.addPartenza(partenza);
    bus.addDest(destinazione);
    bus.addData(data);
    bus.addOraPart(ora_partenza);
    bus.addOraArr(ora_arrivo);
    bus.addRit(ritardo);
}

for (string s: corsa){
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

This code is meant to be a class of a Bus Corporation.

This is the text file

```
5   //number of corsa
534 Scuole Borsellino 10/10 16:00 17:00 0
534 Scuole Borsellino 16/10 18:00 19:00 5
534 Scuole Borsellino 16/10 19:00 20:00 3
722 Borsellino Dusmet 19/10 13:30 14:25 10
722 Borsellino Dusmet 19/10 14:30 15:25 10
```

I'm willing to copy every single line into a vector of strings, but I guess spaces are killing the process.

////UPDATE/////

```
while(getline(aprifile, buffer , '\n'))
{
  corsa.push_back(buffer);
}
for(string s : corsa)
{
  s >> tratta >> partenza >> destinazione >> data >> ora_partenza >> ora_arrivo >> ritardo;
}
```

the

```
s >> tratta >> partenza >> destinazione >> data >> ora_partenza >> ora_arrivo >> ritardo;
```

gives me an error, how should I parse the content now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213292/discussion-on-question-by-avengerscarlet-i-want-to-copy-a-whole-text-file-line-i).

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually parsing the lines at all.

Your loop reads a line from `aprifile` into `buffer`, then pushes that `buffer` *as-is* into `corsa`, then reads 6 more space-delimited values *from the next line of `aprifile`* and puts them into `bus` which is then ignored.

In other words, your loop is reading too much on each iteration. Your reading and storage of data does not follow the format of the file at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

...

ifstream aprifile;
string buffer;
vector<AmtCatania> corsa;
int num_corsa;

aprifile.open("corse.txt");
if (!aprifile.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Registro non aperto!" << endl;
    return -1;
}

getline(aprifile, buffer);
istringstream(buffer) >> num_corsa;

for(int i = 0; (i < num_corsa) && getline(aprifile, buffer); ++i)
{
    string partenza;
    string destinazione;
    string data;
    string ora_partenza;
    string ora_arrivo;
    string ritardo;
    string tratta;

    istringstream(buffer) >> partenza >> destinazione >> data >> ora_partenza >> ora_arrivo >> ritardo >> tratta;

    AmtCatania bus;
    bus.addPartenza(partenza);
    bus.addDest(destinazione);
    bus.addData(data);
    bus.addOraPart(ora_partenza);
    bus.addOraArr(ora_arrivo);
    bus.addRit(ritardo);
    bus.addTratta(tratta);

    corsa.push_back(bus);
}

for (AmtCatania &bus: corsa){
    // print bus as needed...
}
```